# Java: Inheriting a generic class and setting its type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a generic Link class (to implement a linked list), as seen below:

```
class Link<T> {
  protected T next;

  public T getNext() { return next; }
  public void setNext(T newnext) { next = newnext; }

}  // end class Link
```

Now, I want another class called Card to inherit from this.

```
class Card extends Link {
...
}
```

However, I want it to return a Card object for getNext(). How do I do this?

Originally, the Link class was not generic, but then I had to perform a cast on getNext() every time I wanted to use it. I was having a seemingly related null pointer issue, so I wanted to clear this out of the way.

Comment: The solution below works great. The null pointer issue may come up in another question when I get around to it :).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify that the generic parameter type for `Link` to be `Card` in `Card`:

```
class Card extends Link<Card>
```

This assigns `Card` to the generic type parameter `T` from `Link`.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I was having hard time getting my head around this strange combination of generics and inheritance. Works great.